# What is the most simple setup for a MEAN stack docker container to have the same config on OS X and DigitalOcean?

Tags: javascript, macos, git, docker, sails.js

I am playing around with a MEAN javascript project.
(mongoDB + angular + sails.js + node.js)
As I am offline a lot of the time, I'd like to keep my dev environment, running in a docker container, on OS X laptop, using boot2docker.

The 'production' (not actual production, just somewhere I deploy to to show it to friends) is a Digital Ocean droplet running Ubuntu as host and hopefully the same docker container.

I expect that the environment won't change very often and that I can continue using git push/pull to push just the code changes.

Do I need anything else other than what I described above?
Do I need Vagrant, for example to deploy that docker container or is that an overkill?
Can docker specify all all my needs, that is the right version of node.js, sails etc?
Is there a ready made container I can reuse or modify rather than starting from scratch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answers to your questions:

*Do I need anything else other than what I described above?*

What you described sounds very reasonable. But keep in mind that you don't want to use **one** docker container, but rather **one container per service**. That means: one container running mongo, one container running node, and so on. That is a Docker best practice.

*Do I need Vagrant, for example to deploy that docker container or is that an overkill?*

It sounds like your rather simple setup does not require Vagrant. You can use Dockerfiles to build images that have everything you need installed. See the [Dockerfile Reference](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/) and [Dockerfile best Practices](https://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/).

*Can docker specify all my needs, that is the right version of node.js, sails etc?*

Yes, every Docker image has a certain version of the service that will run inside the container. That's one of the points of using containers.

*Is there a ready made container I can reuse or modify rather than starting from scratch?*

Yes, there are many ready made containers to be found on the [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/). Use these images as a base when writing your Dockerfiles to install anything additionally to what is supplied within the image on Docker Hub.

Also, check out [Volumes](https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/) to figure out how to handle source code in development.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. I also found a tutorial for node.js, that introduces nginx reverse proxy on top of all that, but that seems unnecessary and harder to debug, until I actually use it in production.

Comment: One more thing is boot2docker seems like the default option on OS X, so it should be the option to go when I inevitably need community support, but I was thinking of actually setting a fully fledged VirtualBox install and a full ubuntu image, to have the same host OS as the DigitalOcean droplet?

Comment: nginx as a reverse proxy: That would be just an additional linked container. So setup is only: get image, configure nginx as reverse proxy. If it runs on a different machine, I recommend [Ambassadors](https://docs.docker.com/articles/ambassador_pattern_linking/).

Comment: boot2docker is the recommended way for OS X. Since you are using docker containers, you do not need to have the same environment on the dev machine and on production (where you run the containers). Ubuntu or whatever will be inside the containers. So if you run the same nginx container on ubuntu and for example red hat, it would be the same system inside the container. That's kind of the point of containers.

Comment: For Digital Ocean you can test out the new (and not yet stable) [Machine](https://github.com/docker/machine), [Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/), and [Swarm](https://github.com/docker/swarm/). Of course you can also use Machine (and Compose) on your local dev machine to simplify running the required services.