# How to manage multiple backend stacks for development?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mean-stack

I am looking for the best/simplest way to manage a local development environment for multiple stacks. For example on one project I'm building a **MEAN** stack backend.

I was recommended to use **docker**, however I believe it would complicate the deployment process because shouldn't you have one container for mongo, one for express etc? As found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942840/what-is-the-most-simple-setup-for-a-mean-stack-docker-container-to-have-the-same) question on stack.

How do developers manage multiple environments **without VMs**?
And in particular, what are best practices doing this on ubuntu?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

With Docker-Compose you can easily create multiple containers in one go. For development, the containers are usually configured to mount a local folder into the containers filesystem. This way you can easily work on your code and have live reloading. A sample docker-compse.yml could look like this:

```
version: '2' services:   node:
    build: ./node
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./node:/src
      - /src/node_modules
    links:
     - mongo
    command: nodemon --legacy-watch /src/bin/www

  mongo:
    image: mongo
```

You can then just type

```
docker-compose up
```

And you Stack will be up in seconds.