# How to manage multiple symfony projects in a development computer

Tags: symfony, proxy

I've seen some post, including [How to manage multiple backend stacks for development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124301/how-to-manage-multiple-backend-stacks-for-development), but nothing related to use lxc for a stable, safe and separate development environment, matching the production environment and regardless the desktop and/or linux distribution.

There was a feature previous to symfony cli release that allowed to specify a socket via ip:port, and this allowed to use different names in /etc/hosts using the 127.0.0.0/8 loopback network, so I could always use "bin/console server:start -p:myproject:8000", and I knew that using http://myproject:8000 (specified in /etc/hosts) I could access my project and keep the sessions, etc.

The symfony cli, as far as I've tried, doesn't allow this. Reading the docs, there's a built-in proxy in symfony cli, but though I've set a couple of projects to use this in the container, clicking on the list doesn't open the project (with .wip suffix), and issues an error about proxy redirections. If I browse to the port and ip of the container ip, it works perfectly, but the port is something that can change with every reboot of the container.

If there's nothing that can be set on the proxy side to solve this scenario, I'd ask to take back the socket feature that existed previously, so I can manage this situation as I used to do before, and solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've finally found a good solution. I've [created an issue](https://github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/issues/178) to improve the situation that seemed not to work, so I'll try to explain for whoever might be interested.

I've setup the proxy server built-in with the symfony cli, but instead of allowing it to run with the defaults, I've had to specify --host=proxyhost (resolvable from the host) and setting proxy exceptions for .com, .org, .net, .tv, etc, together with setting a name to attach for every project (issuing `symfony proxy:domain:attach myproject` from inside the project dir), I can go to http://myproject.wip just like http://proxyhost:portX, no matter which port is portX.